# How to get all records on the basis of Search String In sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch all the records on the basis of Search string

E.G.

Column name: `FileName`

```
MasterRoomTwo.jpg
BedRoom.png
MasterbedRoom.gif
```

and in simple scenario I can use

```
Declare @FileName  nvarchar(60) = NULL
set @FileName  = '.jpg'

SELECT * 
FROM JobAttachment 
WHERE AND Tags LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@FileName  ,FileName  ) + '%' 
ORDER BY updated DESC
```

but in my case I will get like

```
set @FileName  = '.jpg,.Png,gif'
```

So how to make query like this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: so as i understand you need all data from table where exists '.jpg' , '.png' , '.gif' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. **Split the input string** and use `charindex`

```
SELECT 'MasterRoomTwo.jpg' a INTO   #temp UNION
SELECT 'BedRoom.png' UNION
SELECT 'MasterbedRoom.gif' 

DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(60) 

SET @FileName = '.jpg,.Png,gif'

SELECT *
FROM   #temp
        JOIN (SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) fs
                   FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@FileName, ',', '</M><M>')
                                        + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                          CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) ad
on  Charindex(fs, a) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM   JobAttachment a
       JOIN (SELECT t1.nod.value('.', 'varchar(50)') tags
             FROM   (SELECT Cast('<N>.'
                                 + Replace(Replace(@FileName, '.', ''), ',', '</N><N>.')
                                 + '</N>' AS XML) AS format) t
                    CROSS APPLY format.nodes('/N') AS t1(nod)
             WHERE  t1.nod.value('.', 'varchar(50)') <> '.') fileformat
         ON a.tag LIKE ( '%' + fileformat.tags + '%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic condition as

```
Declare @FileName  nvarchar(60) = NULL
set @FileName  = '.jpg,.Png,gif'


--append a comma to the string to get correct results with empty strings 
--or strings with a single value (no commas)
SET @FileName = @FileName + ',';

declare @x XML
declare @FileSearch nvarchar(max)
select  @x = cast( '<F>' + replace ( @FileName,',','</F><F>') + '</F>' as xml)      
select @FileSearch = stuff( isnull(@FileSearch , '') +
                    ' OR FileName Like ''%'+ isnull(t.value('.','nvarchar(60)'),'') 
                    +'%''' ,1,3,'')
from @x.nodes('/F') as x(t)
```

And then create dynamic query to get desired results:

```
set @sql = 'select * from test where ' -- entire query goes here
            + @FileSearch

exec sp_executesql  @sql
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/BXF6674)</kbd>